# Gatsby SEO using JSON+LD for FAQs page - How to avoid duplicating content?

Tags: gatsby, json-ld, structured-data, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to add FAQs structured data(JSON+LD) for [one of my blog pages](https://blog.squaredeal.tax/texas-homestead-exemption/). My blog is powered by Gatsby. I referred to [gatsby-plugin-next-seo's guide page](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-next-seo/#faq). Here is the example presented:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FAQJsonLd } from 'gatsby-plugin-next-seo';

export default () => (
  <>
    <FAQJsonLd
      questions={[
        { question: 'What?', answer: 'Stand' },
        { question: 'How?', answer: 'Effort' },
        { question: 'Why?', answer: 'Peace' },
      ]}
    />

    <h1>What?</h1>
    <p>Stand</p>

    <h1>How?</h1>
    <p>Effort</p>

    <h1>Why?</h1>
    <p>Peace</p>
  </>
);
```

Content from the article body have been replicated within the JSON+LD section. Is there a way to avoid this duplication? [D-R-Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to fill `FAQJsonLd` with your article content?

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to programmatically fill FAQJsonLd, instead of manual copy+paste.

Comment: How's your article structure? Is it a markdown?

Comment: Yes, it is markdown.

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering if there is a way to programmatically fill FAQJsonLd,
> instead of manual copy+paste.

One thing that comes to my mind is to create custom fields inside the markdown (if you have the option) aside from the HTML/body of the markdown.

You can emulate the question/answer array using something like:

```
---
title: Some Dummy Title
questionsSection:
  - question1:
    question: Some question?
    answer: Some answer
   - question2:
    question: Some question 2?
    answer: Some answer 2  
---
The body of the article
```

*Note: check the structure, maybe you don't need to nest each question/answer inside a new array position (delimited by hyphen, `-`). I haven't tested the structure, you may need to refine it but get the idea*

In this case, you can parse `questionsSection` for each markdown article and pass it directly to `FAQJsonLd` component like:

```
<FAQJsonLd
  questions={questionsSection}
/>
```

As I said, if the structure of `questionsSection` doesn't fit your specs, you can always [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the array.

My idea relies on creating a custom section for each markdown with the FAQs content to avoid parsing the `html` to find the headings of the posts (which may contain the questions). That markdown section, ideally, should be an array of objects to fit `FAQJsonLd` specs.

You can even use a JSON notation inside like:

```
---
title: Some Dummy Title
questionsSection: '{"questions":[{question: "Question 1", answer: "Answer 1"}]}'
---
The body of the article
```

The idea is exactly the same. Use whatever is more comfortable with you.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks.